# How to set & retrieve a cookie via an executable bash script that is on the web

Tags: bash, environment-variables

A simple bash script that can set a cookie when
executed via web :

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Set-Cookie: eee=1"
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
echo "test"
```

I replaced the entire codes above with the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os

print 'Set-Cookie: eee=1'
print 'Content-Type: text\n'

print '<html><body>'

a = os.environ.get('HTTP_COOKIE')
print a

print '</body></html>'
```

this one can now both set and retrieve a cookie.

but it is no longer a bash script. it is a python script.

the question is.. how to retrieve the cookie via bash script itself.. ?

Comment: Do read http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters — especially if you're going to process data from a remote client. In a shell script, `echo $VARIABLE` does not print the value of the variable, it does further processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your second script in `bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Set-Cookie: eee=1"
echo "Content-Type: text"

echo "<html><body>"

printf '%s\n' "$HTTP_COOKIE"

echo "</body></html>"
```

`os.environ.get('HTTP_COOKIE')` gets the evironment variable called `HTTP_COOKIE`, within `bash` you can easly call the variable with `"$HTTP_COOKIE"`.